# Unable to upload image in Redactor

Tags: jquery

I am using **Redactor editor (version: 10.0.2)** in my code. I want to upload images only from web. I am unable to upload image in editor. My code is as follows:

```
$('#helptextDescription').redactor({
                minHeight: '223px',
                maxHeight: '223px',
                minwidth: '640px',
                maxwidth: '640px',
                buttons: ['html', 'formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted',
                          'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', 'image',
                          'table', 'link', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule'],
                buttonSource: true,
                deniedTags: ['applet'],
                removeClasses: false,
                replaceDivs: false,
                imageUpload: '/WebClient/Images',
                imageUploadCallback: function (image, json) {
                    $(image).attr('id', json.id);
                },
                imageUploadErrorCallback: function (json) {
                    alert('error');
                }              
            });
```